# Push Service plugin for BlackBerry WebWorks 2.0.0.54 error (Cordova 3.2) (newest versions of both SDKs)

Tags: html, plugins, cordova, blackberry, push

I'm trying to use the Push Service plugin in my BlackBerry Webworks app (BB10 in HTML5).

I added the plugin through the command line like the documentation says, and checked that the com.blackberry.push folder was infact inside my plugins folder in my project. I ran the app in my device and the Web Inspector gave the next error:

*TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'window.webworks.defineReadOnlyField')*

This error appears when the plugin tries to define the push constants like SUCCESS or INVALID_PPG_SUBSCRIBER_STATE, so obviously the plugin never starts to work and I can't use the push service.

I have my Push credentials fine (they work fine in my OS 7 app), and I was very carefull when I wrote the config.xml file. Here it is:

```
<widget id="Sample" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" version="0.0.1">
<name>Sample</name>
<license href="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"/>
<author email="something@somwhat.com" href="http://www.something.com">Something</author>
<content src="splash.html"/>

<access uri="http://www.mypushserver.com/Registro_Portalesv4/modules/Register" subdomains="true"></access>

<access origin="*"/>
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
<description>Example</description>
<icon src="img/icono.png"/>
<feature id="blackberry.app"/>
<feature id="blackberry.push" />
<feature id="blackberry.system" />
<feature id="blackberry.invoked" />
<feature id="blackberry.ui.dialog" />
<feature id="org.apache.cordova" required="true" version="1.0.0" />
<rim:permissions>*
<rim:permit>access_shared</rim:permit>
<rim:permit>post_notification</rim:permit>
<rim:permit system="true">_sys_use_consumer_push</rim:permit>
<rim:permit>read_device_identifying_information</rim:permit> 
<rim:permit>access_pimdomain_messages</rim:permit>
<rim:permit>bbm_connect</rim:permit> 
<rim:permit>run_when_backgrounded</rim:permit>
</rim:permissions>
<rim:invoke-target id="example.sample.invoke.push">
<type>APPLICATION</type>
<filter>
<action>bb.action.PUSH</action>
<mime-type>application/vnd.push</mime-type>
</filter>
</rim:invoke-target>
<!-- Have an invoke entry here for when a notification is clicked on in the BlackBerry Hub -->
<!-- This will cause the application to be opened -->
<rim:invoke-target id="example.sample10.invoke.open">
<type>APPLICATION</type>
<filter>
<action>bb.action.OPEN</action>
<mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
</filter>
</rim:invoke-target> 
</widget>
```

What I did notice was that the function "window.webworks.defineReadOnlyField" is located in the webworks-1.0.4.11.js file wich I don't have included in my project because I'm using cordova.js as the [BlackBerry WebWorks Documentation, Upgrading to WebWorks 2.0](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/beta/upgrading_to_webworks_20.html) suggested. So I think that maybe the push plugin is not updated for the new SDK or I'm missing something as well.

Any ideas? Thanks in advanced!

PS: I'm porting my app from Phonegap Android, and worked fine when I ported it to Blackberry, except for the plugins, wich I had to add and adapt so they could work (except for the push plugin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solves by downloading the newest version of the PushService Plugin (updated 10 hours after I posted the question), that has fixed all the problems I mentioned on my question.

Also, don't forget to add a  tag with the ppg url to you config.xml file, otherwise the push service won't work.